# How to create the new payment module for redirect into payment gateway website in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment

I have referred so many blogs, I didn't get the correct way to implement the payment gateway with redirection into payment site

Also confused whether the order entry is created in the database Before going the payment site? or After complete the payment process?

While click on the "place order" button, will do the following.

1. Create the new order entry in the database.
2. Get the order related information's like order id, amount, currency, First name, last name.. etc
3. Create the gateway URL, using the external library from the given information(API key, username) and order related information(amount, order id, billing address, success URL, Failed URL,.. etc)
4. Redirect to the gateway URL.
5. Once the payment is completed, the external payment site will provide the payment information into given Web-hook URL.
6. The web-hook URL get payment information and update the order status by order id.
7. Redirect into success/failure page based on the payment status.

How to proceed into the correct way and make it works perfectly.

Can you explain with code examples?